# Converting Derived Type to Base Type

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to learn type casting from base class to derived class. This sample will show you what I am trying to do. I know this is not a valid solution. I am just trying to create a dynamic architecture for my software and open for advices, solutions.

```
enum EComponentType
{
    Base = 0,
    Material = 1
};

class FComponent
{
public:
    FComponent() { m_type = EComponentType::Base; }

    EComponentType type() { return m_type; }

protected:
    EComponentType m_type;

};

class FMaterial : public FComponent
{
public:
    FMaterial() { m_type = EComponentType::Material; }

    void setValue(int value) { m_value = value; }
    int value() { return m_value; }

private:
    int m_value;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FMaterial material;
    material.setValue(22);

    QVector<FComponent> Components;
    Components << material;

    for (int i = 0; i < Components.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (Components[i].type())
        {
        case EComponentType::Material:

            FMaterial material = (FMaterial)(Components[i]); // --> invalid of course

            int value = material.value();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Update 1:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QVector<FComponent*> Components;

    FMaterial material;
    material.setValue(22);


    Components << &material;

    for (int i = 0; i < Components.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (Components[i]->type())
        {
        case EComponentType::Material:

            FMaterial *m = static_cast<FMaterial*>(Components[i]);

            int value = m->getValue();
            qDebug() << value;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So is this a good choice due to performance or any other reasons? There will be lots of classes and many types?

Comment: If you store base class instances by value in a container then this will never work because you can not put derived instances in a container by value. You have to store base class pointers `FComponent*` in the container in your case. In this case you can create derived instances with `new` and then the derived instance pointer can easily be casted into base class pointer and it can be put to the container. Also don't forget to provide a virtual destroctor in the base class if you `delete` the instances using the base class pointers.

Comment: You should **never** need to check the type of anything, virtual functions are there to handle differences between base and derived automatically. And casting derived to base is nonsense, an object of derived *is* of the base class. Just like you, as [SO] participant, still are a person.

Comment: @vonbrand can you explain more or just make a sample post for example derived class B has a member "int b" and derived class C has a member "int c". How to use them. How to read their values'

Comment: @vonbrand Exactly. There are only a few cases that happen once in several years where I employ a hack similar to OP's pattern as a performance hack to avoid several virtual calls in a row... Not to mention that in reality most desktop applications are far from being performance critical anywhere in their code so nice design has priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not agree with your overall design here is how to fix your solution:

Use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` and it will work. `dynamic_cast` will also work if you put at least one virtual function to the base class but its an overkill and would be redundant along with your type enum.

EDIT: Also I've just noticed that you try to cast values, in case of classes you have to do the casting on class pointers or references!

```
class FComponent
{
public:
    // Withtout this if you delete an FComponent* then the destructor of the derived class isn't called.
    virtual ~FComponent() {}
};

class FMaterial : public FComponent
{

};

int test()
{
    QVector<FComponent*> Components;
    FMaterial* material = new FMaterial;
    Components << material;

    for (int i = 0; i < Components.size(); i++)
    {
        switch (Components[i].type())
        {
        case EComponentType::Material:
            FMaterial* material = static_cast<FMaterial*>(Components[i]);
            int value = material->value();
            break;
        }
    }

    // Somewhere later in your code....            
    for (int i = 0; i < Components.size(); i++)
        delete Components[i];
    // TODO: remove all deleted pointers from Components

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: error: C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'FComponent' to 'FMaterial'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: You only can cast pointers or references, not the actual class types.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü in case of classes you have to perform the cast on class pointers or class references. You have to cast a `Base*` to a `Derived*` in order to get it work, if you try to cast by value then it isn't a cast you want, it would be a conversion that wanted to create a new derived instance by converting a base class that wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: Ok. Actualy it was already predictable. I've updated the question.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü see my comment below your question. You have to use pointers. It may be a bit strange if you come from a language (like java) where class types are automatically reference types but in C++ you can use a class by value and by pointer/reference. In case of references it just adds to the confusion that it is actually a pointer but the syntax with what you use it is like that of by-value objects.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü although you have already accepted my solution I added a bit of sample code. The code of course wouldn't compile as I don't have `QVector` and I havent actually compiled/tested it and my `FComponent`/`FMaterial` class is only partially implemented. Note that you need the virtual destructor and finally you have to `delete` all items from the containers (unless you delete the items somewhere else) in order to avoid a leak.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I understood, just "deleting pointers from vectors" is a bit problem now.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü Let's put it a bit more clear: First you delete your component objects with "delete baseclass pointer" statements, and then you still have a vector that contains invalid pointers to memory areas from where you deleted your objects and you gave back those memory areas to your allocator/memory manager. For this reason it is a good practice to empty your container by removing the "invalid pointers" from it.